# How to show tkinter buttons in mac touch bar 2020

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, pycharm, macbookpro-touch-bar

```
from tkinter import *
import PyTouchBar
PyTouchBar.set_customization_identifier("com.madrau.PyTouchBar.touchbar")

root = Tk()
starter = PyTouchBar.TouchBarItems.Button(title='играть', color=(PyTouchBar.Color.green))
PyTouchBar.set_touchbar([starter])
PyTouchBar.prepare_tk_windows(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Used lyb PyTouchBar/tkinter

Code open new modal white widnow 'kt'
And nothing happened on the touchbar. It may be issue with touchbar, i have with physical 'esc' button. How possible to fix it?

changed python v.
PyTouchBar works just with 3+ i using 3.11

apple m1 pro 2020

Comment: Which version is PyTouchBar?

Comment: You mis-spelled `window` as `widnow`.

Comment: @Scott Hunter.. Nope. It is correct PyTouchBar.prepare_tk_windows(root....

Comment: @J.M.Arnold 0.2.0 version